# Ordenar array que me trae todos los elementos en otro array y clasificar los valores

Tags: php, html5, laravel-5

No veo manera de preguntarlo de manera técnica así que me apoyare con imágenes. 
Tengo un array el cual lo obtengo en un request en Laravel 5.6 que contiene los siguiente valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es pasarlos a otro array de manera que vayan quedando asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit1:** Inicialmente el array me llega de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Use un foreach para sacar todos los valores y almacenarlos en el array de la primera imagen.

Codigo usado para convertir el array a como esta en la ultima imagen a como esta en la primera.

```
foreach($fpagos as $fpago){
        foreach($fpago as $dpago){
            //dd($dpago);
            $pagos_n[] = $dpago['name']; 
            $pagos_n[] = $dpago['value'];
        } 
    }
```

**Edit2:** Intente usar el codigo que me pasaste, creo haberlo usado mal porque me arrojo el mismo array sin cambios

```
foreach ($pagos_n as $key => $value){
        $pagos_n[$key];
    }
```

Comment: Coloca el resultado de los array en código para ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo agregue a la pregunta, inicialmente el array me llega como en la ultima imagen.

Comment: ¿Podrías completar la pregunta basándote en datos reales. He intentado hacer una prueba, pero por ejemplo este código `foreach($fpagos as $fpago){  ...` no me crea un array como el que dices. En el `var_dump` que muestras el segundo sub-array (array con clave `1`) por ejemplo es un array de 4 elementos, o sea tiene dos sub-arrays con dos valores bajo las claves `name , value`.  Si la pregunta no se basa en la realidad de los datos veo difícil que se te pueda ayudar de forma adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
<?php

$data=array("t_pago","Efectivo","monto","123","t_pago","Deposito","monto","1234");

foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
{
    echo $data[$key];
}
```

?>

Comment: Es que los valores no son estaticos, agregue el codigo para pasar el array a como se ve en la ultima imagen a como se ve en la primera.

Comment: Pasale tu array dinámico.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
foreach($fpagos as $fpago){
   foreach($fpagos as $dpago){
        foreach($dpago as $key => $value){ 
            $pagos_n[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```